# scrlttr2 - onehalfspacing in main body, singlespace in address

Tags: spacing, formatting, koma-script, scrlttr2, addresses

I'm writing a letter with `scrlttr2` and I want the main body in `\onehalfspacing`. But even with

```
\begin{onehalfspacing}
  TEXT BODY
\end{onehalfspacing}
```

the address is set in one-half spacing as well. This takes up unnecessary space and makes the address too long to fit into the window of a windowed envelope.

I've tried inserting the address into a `singlespace` environment - no effect.
I've searched for a KOMAvar that governs the spacing - nothing (at least nothing I could find.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Jane Doe}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Dover Road 4\\ WH6 TR5 Foobar}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{jane.doe@dover.foo}
\setkomavar{place}{Internet}
\setkomavar{subject}{Foo for foo}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{John Doe\\
Dover Institute\\
Fooroad 1\\
WH6 TR5 Foobar}

\KOMAoptions{fromalign=right,frommobilephone=false,fromemail=true,foldmarks=false}

\begin{onehalfspacing}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}

foo foo foo foo foo foo foo.

\blindtext

\closing{Faithfully,}
\end{onehalfspacing}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Move `\begin{onehalfspacing}` after `\opening{...}`

Comment: That solved it! Thank you so much! (And I feel a little stupid...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\opening` does more than printing the greeting: It sets up the first page. So if you want something to affect only "the text body" it is better to start if after `\opening`. So move `\begin{onehalfspacing}` behind `\opening{...}`.